# selenium webdriver open the chrome but not the whatsappWeb

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from time import sleep

# Create a Service object by specifying the path to chromedriver
chrome_service = Service(executable_path="path\crome.exe")

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\path_file")

# Pass the Service object to webdriver.Chrome()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=options)

# Open WhatsApp Web
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")

sleep(10)
```

When I run this code chrome opens but whatsapp web doesn't open. how to fix that?

I tried using several different methods like:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

and:

```
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36")
```

but none of them worked

Comment: it works alright when i try to replicate it

Comment: what do you mean by replicate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify the the chrome exectuable path anymore. It's enough that Chrome is installed and set as default browser.

I tested this and it's working fine:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36")
#options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\path_file")

# Pass the Service object to webdriver.Chrome()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Open WhatsApp Web
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")

sleep(10)
```

Comment: it worked but i want to use the `options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\path_file")` too. I tried to insert this options function and the same problem i mentioned repeat. Do you know how to fix it please?

Comment: just add the path to your user data folder